# Giving XML File a Relative Link to a Schema?

Tags: xml, xsd, relative-path

I have an XML file and I've used Visual Studios 2010 to create a basic XML schema for this file. I need to link the two files.

Here is my directory structure:

```
xml/
  .xml
  .xml
xsd/
   .xsd
   .xsd

<root
   xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="xml_schemas/accounts.xsd"
>
```

Is it possible to do this? How can I do this? I'm getting an error about needing pairs, the first being the namespace URI and the second being the file location. The xml and xsd are on a local machine only.

Answer (score 1):

Your schema location always needs to be a list of **pairs** where the first part of the pair is a namespace and the second is a URI.

In your case:

```
<root
   xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com ../xsd/accounts.xsd">
```

In cases of schemas with no namespace, you would use `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation`, which contains only a URI.